# 301 redirect in htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I am facing problems when creating a 301 redirect on my site. When I am creating a redirect the browser is showing the full qherysting rather than directing the page.

**eg. I am wanting to direct /contact to /contact-us**

What I am getting is:

**/contact-us?page=contact**

Here is the code from my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteBase /

redirect 301 /contact /contact-us 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: because of RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L], $1 is accepting /contact as a parameter :P

Comment: But the rewrite rule is fine for creating www.mysite.co.uk/contact, if i direct this page why would it do the same and direct to www.mysite.co.uk/contact-us?

Comment: ok Let me frame the answer. You try it, if it doesn't work, comment there, cool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a mod_alias/mod_rewrite conflict. The path processing pipeline is handling the 2 things separately. You can just stick with mod_rewrite and replace

```
redirect 301 /contact /contact-us
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact-us [L,R=301]
```

So the rewriting will **stop** once it gets here and the last rule never gets applied. Otherwise, mod_alias will redirect the URL, but not until it's run the URI through mod_rewrite, thus you get this globbed together redirect. If you don't mind a trailing **?**, you could also add it to the end of your redirect target:

```
redirect 301 /contact /contact-us?
```

so that the query string won't get appended.

Comment: I think this answer is better. But, it might affect his application which requires getting values as ?page= ?? because he has mentioned `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]` . Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @KarmicDice After the redirect, the URI will be `/contact-us` which means it will be rewritten to `/index.php?page=contact-us`, if that's not what's intended, then why redirect at all?

Comment: @KarmicDice Additionally, an new rule could be used to re-rewrite the `contact-us` back to `contact` if placed before the last index.php rule: `RewriteRule ^contact-us$ /index.php?page=contact [L]

Comment: RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact-us [L,R=301] worked great! The main problem for this was that Google was indexing 2 pages 

/contact-us?page=contact and /contact-us which would not be good for as it may be classed as duplicate content. Works fine now, thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteRule ^contact[/]?$ /contact-us [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)[/]?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I don't get redirected at all when I use these rules, but I get served the content at `/index.php?page=contact`

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

> Redirect 301 /contact http://www.domain.com/contact-us

Use the full url.

Comment: This does't work either, I get redirected to `http://www.domain.com/contact-us?page=contact`, the query string is still there.